# Number of paths in a graph as a function of depth

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, potential-theory

This problem has been bugging me for weeks now.

Consider a infinite graph, with a given degree distribution. Now, for the sake of intuition, consider that each vertex includes a match. We pick a match and set it on fire. After this, all the adjacent vertices are also ignited.

My question is, what is the average number of match that will be set alight as the propagation from progresses?

A, very, simplistic approach would be that on every iteration the number of newly fired matches is multiplied with the mean degree of the node. However, this ignores the fact that the graph will loop with itself.

What tool could we use to solve this problem? It does smell a bit like generating functions..

Comment: I'm not sure you can answer this question with degree distribution alone. Consider an infinite cubic graph. It may be a path with an additional neighbor per vertex, and each turn you will burn a constant number of matches. On the other hand, consider an ever-growing binary tree - each turn the number of ignited matches will increase.

Comment: @dtldarek : don't you think the resistance distance problem, solved by the inverse of the Laplacian matrix, is part of the solution ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance

Comment: @user1952009 Or part of some estimate, but we don't have enough info.